# vscode "Find box" selector name

Tags: visual-studio-code, theming

Anyone knows the selector to customize the color of the Find box? (the small box that shows at the top/right when you press Ctrl+F where you type the search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, go to [theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) and search for `find`

Most are here: [Editor Widget colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-widget-colors)

but you'll find a few others, like for the input boxes that also affect the Find Widget.

Comment: Thank you. For the record, "editorWidget.foreground" and "errorForeground" were what I was looking for. (being in a dark theme to see de account of finds or the error message)